# Uncaught TypeError: b.opt.map is not a function(Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have gone through few questions related to my query but I did not get solution.

My problem scenario is:

I have a accordion in that we are adding checkboxes dyanamically as below

[image]

After adding checkboxes these three will be shown in the accordion like below.

[image]

I am not facing any problem If I add more than one checkbox.

But if I add only one check box instead more than one I am getting below error.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: b.opt.map is not a function
```

If I am adding more than one check box it is not returning any error.

Below is the code for adding more than one check boxes(works fine if multiple checkboxes).

```
 case 'checkbox':                          
     b.array = {};
    $(e.target).find("input[type='text']").each(function(e){ 
    if($(this).attr('id')){
          b.array[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val(); }
     }); 
      b.options = b.opt.map(function(v,i) { 
         return [b.array[i], v, b.optval[i]];
     });
      this.edit_checkbox(b);
```

Example:
`b.opt` = Jan and `b.optval` = January

It is returning a string for single value but if there are more one values it is returning an array. So I want to convert string to array.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Example: b.opt = Jan and b.optval = January

Comment: What is the other way to handle this case.

Comment: A string doesn't have map but array has map()...Cant we do it with array's?

Comment: Is it possible using Objects instead map()?

Answer (score 0):

```
 b.array = {};    
$(e.target).find("input[type='text']").each(function(e){ 
if($(this).attr('id')){ 
     b.array[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val(); 
  }
});
if(Array.isArray(b.opt)){
 b.options = b.opt.map(function(v,i) { 
    return [b.array[i], v, b.optval[i]]; });
 }else{
    b.options = [].concat(b.opt).map(function(v,i) { 
          return [v, b.optval]; 
});
}
```

Here I was required to convert string into key value pair array to make it work.